# Share sticker into the Viber.But sticker background become to black

Tags: android

[image]

**I can use below code for share sticker to Viber. But after share sticker background become to black.My sticker is Transparent.Please help me.**

My screen short image link

[image: enter link description here]

```
     Here is my source code:

 Intent sharingIntent = new Intent(android.content.Intent.ACTION_SEND);
 sharingIntent.setType("image/png");

 sharingIntent.putExtra(Intent.EXTRA_STREAM, Uri.parse("file:///sdcard/sticker_demo/"   +transparentstickerpath));              
   startActivity(Intent.createChooser(sharingIntent, "Share via"));
```

Comment: Have you got anu soltion here?